# Magento2: Update Qty of product in bundle

Tags: magento2, jquery, bundled-product

I am updating the quantity of a radio button in a bundle via jQuery: $ ('input. Qty'). Val (4)

Unfortunately the product summary does not change. When I put the value ("4") in the same input field and go with "TAB" to the next element in the product summary is changing.

I guess there is a function I could use to dynamically recalculate the product summary as it works in Magento 1. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

All right, I found a *solution*: Just add a `.trigger('change')`

so the summary is also been updates,

f.e. `$('input.qty').val(15).trigger('change');`